# Multilevel Dropdown Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigationbar, multi-level

I am trying to make a multilevel dropdown menu but only first level is showing in **Desktop View** .
although its working fine in Mobile view but not in Desktop view why ?
you can see in the **residential menu** the Ongrid and OffGrid Option is not visible the menu is visible only till first level i.e Residential and same this goes with **Products** menu

[image]

I want the menu somthing like this

[image]

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {

      // Detect device type
      var isMobile;
      if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          isMobile = true;
      } else {
          isMobile = false;
      }

      if (isMobile) {

        // Navigation - Dropdown menu on mobile
        $('.main-menu > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
          if ($(this).parent().children('ul').length) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          $(this).parent().find('i').toggleClass('open');
          $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
        });

        // Navigation - show & close menu on mobile
        $('.btn-nav-mobile').on('click', function() {
          $(this).addClass('btn-nav-open');
          $('.nav').addClass('nav-open');
          $('.overlay').addClass('overlay-open');
        });
        $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
          $(this).removeClass('overlay-open');
          $('.nav').removeClass('nav-open');
          $('.btn-nav-mobile').removeClass('btn-nav-open');
        });

      }


      
    });
```

```css
    .nav {
      margin-left: auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav {
        overflow: auto;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: -250px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 100;
        transition: all 0.2s;
      }
      .nav.nav-open {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
      }
    }

    .nav .main-menu > li {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 0px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      vertical-align: center;
    }
    .nav .main-menu > li:hover{
      color: #3BA2FF;
    }  
    .nav .main-menu .active {
      color:#3ba2ff
    }


    .header-2 .nav .main-menu > li {
      line-height: 75px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav .main-menu > li {
        display: block;
        line-height: 1 !important;
        margin-left: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
      }
      .nav .main-menu > li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 20px;  
      }
    }

    .nav .main-menu > li i {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 20px;
      transition: all 0.2s; 
    } 


    .nav .main-menu > li i.open {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav .main-menu > li i {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    /* .nav .main-menu > li:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 25%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 4px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #3BA2FF;
      transition: all 0.2s;

    }  */


    .green .nav .main-menu > li:after {
      background-color: #3AE374;
    }

    .lightblue .nav .main-menu > li:after {
      background-color: #3BA2FF;
    }

    .red .nav .main-menu > li:after {
      background-color: #ff4d4d;
    }

    .no-radius .nav .main-menu > li:after {
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav .main-menu > li:after {
        top: 35px;
        left: 5px;
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    /* .nav .main-menu > li.active:after{
      visibility: visible;
      width: 50px;
      transition: all 0.3s;

    } */


    .nav .main-menu > li:hover ul {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      transform: translateY(5px);
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .nav .main-menu > li ul {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translateY(15px);
      width: 200px;
      left: -10px;
      top: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 20;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    .no-radius .nav .main-menu > li ul {
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav .main-menu > li ul {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }

    .nav .main-menu > li ul li {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 0;
      line-height: 19px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .nav .main-menu > li ul li {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
      }
    }

    .nav .main-menu > li ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 13px 15px;
      color: #8c8c8c;
      transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    .nav .main-menu > li ul li a:hover {
      color: #333333;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      transform: translateX(5px);
    }

    .btn-nav-mobile {
      width: 25px;
      display: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #get{
      margin-left: -20px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .btn-nav-mobile {
        display: block;
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-bottom:20px
      }
      #get{
        display:none;
      }
    }

    .btn-nav-mobile span {
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      float: right;
      height: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #7b80eb;
    }

    .no-radius .btn-nav-mobile span {
      border-radius: 0;
    }


    .btn-nav-mobile span:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <header class="header" >
    <div class="main-bar" id="mainb">
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="btn-nav-mobile">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
        <div class="solar_logo">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="solar-installation-logo"></a>
        </div>

      <nav class="nav">
       <ul class="main-menu">
       <li>
         <a href="index.html" style="margin-left:-15px;font-weight: 600" >Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="about.html" style="margin-left:-15px;font-weight: 600">About Us</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="service.html"style="font-weight: 600;margin-left:-15px;">Services</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="service.html">Residential</a>
        <ul id="drop">
          <li><a href="service.html#ongrid">On Grid Solar Power Plant</a></li>
          <li><a href="service.html#offgrid">Off Grid Solar Power Plant</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="commercial.html">Commercial</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
       <a href="Products.html"style="font-weight: 600;margin-left:-15px;">Solar Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="service.html#residential">Solar Modules</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html#residential">Solar Inverter</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html#commercial">Solar Batteries</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html#institutional">BOS Systems</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html#institutional">Solar Pumps</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html#institutional">Solar Street Light</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
     <a href="carrer.html" style="font-weight: 600;margin-left:-15px;" >Electric Vehicles</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="service.html#residential">Electric Vehicles</a></li>
      <li><a href="service.html#residential">Electric Vehicles Batteries</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"style="font-weight: 600;margin-left:-15px;">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class="solar_mdl_btn"> 
      <a href="#exampleModal" class="solar_btn" id="get" data-toggle="modal">Get A Quote</a>
      </li>

       </ul>
     </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: Perhaps if you changed your snippet to show something. For now I just see a blank page...

Comment: please open this snippet in full page and hover to the services section then residential section the you will get to know that its not showing the menu after residential section

Comment: Where is sub sub menu should appear? Because, after some plays, it appears below the sub menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crtRs.png

Comment: i want this to be shown to the right side of main menu

Comment: something like this https://codepen.io/rafonzoo/pen/bqeeyj  [Product --> window10 --> window10 pro etc.